# Error al intentar agregar angular material a un proyecto Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

cloné un proyecto el cuál es nuevo, así que esta desde cero. Hice un `npm install` y todo bien, ahora, cuándo ejecuta el comando `ng add @angular/material` me arroja este montón errores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

además, cuándo ejecuto ng serve me muestra este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe a que se deba esto?

**Actualización:**

Versión de Angular Cli:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi package.json antes de ejecutar npm install:

```js
{
  "name": "angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.28",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.28",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

Después de ejecutar npm install:

```js
{
  "name": "angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.28",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.28",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Muestra el package.json, el que clonaste y el que quedó después del npm i

Comment: @sgClaudia98 listo.

Comment: @sgClaudia98 además, cuando intento ng serve también me muestra otro error, lo acabo de agregar a la pregunta también.

Comment: Entonces eso es lo primero, lograr que no serve funcione. Luego material debe funcionar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba lo siguiente en el proyecto clonado

1. Borra node_modules y package.lock
2. En package.json cambia todos los ^ por ~
3. Npm i
4. Ng serve

Si funciona...
5. ng add @angular/material@8.3.2

Explicación

Lo que pasó aquí fue que como el repo que clonaste tiene una versión vieja.
Al dar npm i todo lo que tenga

^ puede realizar actualizaciones menores y de parches

~ puede realizar actualizaciones de parches

Muchas veces cuando actualizas una versión otro paquete o dependencia necesita actualizarse también, esto puede dar errores de breaking changes en el código existente.
Por eso es que al corregir estás actualizaciones automáticas y limitar las solo a los parches ya no te salen los errores de paquetes con distinto número de versión o menor al requerido.
También te busque el angular material que aparece en la doc para angular 8 y esa fue la versión que te compartí.

Saludos y buen día

Comment: Solo borraré package-lock, ya que al no hacer un npm i no tengo la carpeta node_modules, ya que es un repo clonado.

Comment: Si ,me lo imaginé, pero por si acaso se quedaba de hacer rollback en el git

Comment: Esto funcionó, podrías explicarme lo que se hizo? y por que de la forma común (haciendo un npm install ) no funcionaba y tenía esos errores ?

Comment: @JulianProg Ya actualice con una explicación